# Category 4 data based on the number range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, categories

Use case: The number of rows will be dynamic each time. I will need to assign the category based on the range of number.

I know the formula for Excel and do it one by one:

```
=IF(A2>90,"High",IF(A2>60,"Medium","Low"))
```

I will like to add this in VBA with a loop

I can get it going for one by one but i will like to assign a value so it will go into a loop.

- step 1) find out how many actual value within one column
- step 2) each cell will have a value and assign a tag based on the range (either A, B, C or D)
- step 3) add the tag result back the spreadsheet adjacent to the original row

Comment: If you are on Microsoft-365 then you could dynamically do it by formula only. Show your input data and desired output as text table in your post.

Comment: Welcome Richard! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour